# Stacking an array and putting it into a dat file

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

So far in my code:

```
a = np.array((1,2,3,4))
b = np.array((11,21,31,41))
np.column_stack((a,b))

array([[1, 11],

      [2, 21], 

      [3, 31],

      [4. 41],
```

I am wondering how do I set my code so that I could write the columns onto a dat file?

Comment: what do you mean by a "dat" file? You want to write all values as sequential bytes in a binary file?

Comment: yes. I just want a file that has array a as the 1st column and b as the second column in a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `np.savetxt`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

```
In [2]: a = np.array((1,2,3,4))

In [3]: b = np.array((11,21,31,41))

In [5]: c = np.column_stack((a,b))

In [7]: np.savetxt('test.dat', c)

In [8]: !cat test.dat
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.100000000000000000e+01
2.000000000000000000e+00 2.100000000000000000e+01
3.000000000000000000e+00 3.100000000000000000e+01
4.000000000000000000e+00 4.100000000000000000e+01
```

You can always specify the formatting using the `fmt` option in `np.savetxt`:

```
In [9]: np.savetxt('test.dat', c, fmt='%d')

In [10]: !cat test.dat
1 11
2 21
3 31
4 41
```

Comment: @user1821176 No problem. Just as a note, if this solution is correct and answers your original question, then you should accept the solution.